# How to get a cookie in a subdomain using authjs

Tags: reactjs, typescript, cookies, next.js, next-auth

I want to be able to share the login status, so I use nextjs and authjs, I see the session in the console of the subdomain, but I can't get any information using `useSession` in my project.
[console cookie](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yulIY.png)

`[...nextauth.ts]`

```
  cookies: {
    sessionToken: {
      name: `${useSecureCookies ? '__Secure-' : ''}next-auth.session-token`,
      options: {
        httpOnly: true,
        sameSite: 'lax',
        path: '/',
        domain: useSecureCookies ? '.domain.com' : undefined,
        secure: useSecureCookies,
      },
    },
  },
```

`header.tsx`

```
import { getCookie } from 'cookies-next'
import { signIn, useSession } from 'next-auth/react'

export const Header: FC = () => {
  const { data: session, status } = useSession()

  const t = useTranslations()

  const sessionToken = getCookie('__Secure-next-auth.session-token')
  console.log('session', session) //null
  console.log('sessionToken', sessionToken) //undefined

return ....
```

How can I use nextjs, authjs to share login status, get cookies